# SQL Server 2019 - Job (SSIS) fails with error "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, package, sql-server-agent, sql-server-2019

I am currently migrating a database from an old SQL Server 2012 to a new system running SQL Server 2019. In addition to the database I am also migrating several SQL Server Agent Jobs.
One of these jobs consists of multiple different steps, one that just runs a PowerShell script and two other steps that are implemented as an SSIS package. When I execute one of the steps that are implemented as SSIS package, I get the following error:

```
The process could not be created for step 2 of job <long hexadecimal number> (reason: The system cannot find the file specified). The step failed.
```

How am I supposed to diagnose this error? I have no idea which file cannot be found and why. Is there no way to get any additional information about this error? I already checked all files involved in the SSIS package such as the package file itself, the configuration file and all files that are accessed during the execution of the step but I cannot find the reason for this error.
Could there be a compatibility issue since the packages are executed in a new SQL Server 2019 instead of the older SQL Server 2012? If so, how can I check if this is actually the case?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Considering this error is from agent, not SSIS, this suggest that agent can't find the package file to execute. Why are you using the FileSystem Deployment method here, rather than SSISDB?

Comment: @Larnu I don't know, I am just migrating the database and the jobs from the old system to the new one. I did not develop it so I have no idea why the SSIS packages are deployed like this. The package files exist and they are located under the path that was configured when creating the jobs so why should it not be able to find the files?

Comment: My initial point stands, however, that error very strongly suggests that the (new) SQL Server host cannot locate the SSIS Package. Either because it doesn't exists, or the Service Account does not have access to where it is located.

Comment: @Larnu I will check it once again just to make sure. I also already granted Full Access on the folder containing the packages to the service account so this should not be the problem. Just to clarify: By "Service Account" do you mean the "Owner" that is configured in the job properties, or which account are you referring to?

Comment: It's been a *long* time (7~ years) since I used anything other than SSISDB for SSIS, but I *think* the SQL Server Agent Service account grabs the file, and then it's executed as the owner; but I am basing that on *very* vague memories. SSISDB is just so significantly better than the other deployment methods that I (and many others) haven't looked back since.

Comment: @Larnu Yeah the system I am migrating is actually really old (it's older than the version-control system in our company). Is there an easy way to maybe migrate it to SSISDB? Maybe that would fix this problem.

Comment: The easier way to "migrate" to SSISDB, in my opinion is to redeploy the project from Visual Studio.

Comment: @Larnu Okay so I just moved the package files directly into a folder on C:, changed the configuration of the job but I still get the exact same error. There is just no way how it could not be able to find the package file on the system.

Comment: Just being on the host doesn't mean that the service account has access to it, @Chris. The default service account, for example, only has access to the directory that SQL Server is installed in, and that's it.

Comment: @Larnu Yeah I know that but the configured owner definitely has access to the folder and the files inside it. However I just noticed that inheritance is disabled for the folder and everything is configured manually instead. I don't know but this looks like a potential problem to me so I'll change it and see if this might solve the problem.

Comment: If the files have different permissions to the folder, and the account does not have access to the files, that would be a problem, yes.

Comment: @Larnu Unfortunately this did not help. I still get the same error. I also checked every single folder from the drive to the actual SSIS package file and the user definitely has access to all of this.

Comment: @Larnu I just changed the owner of the job to my own account (administrator) and I am still getting the exact same error message.

Comment: @Larnu After using a monitoring tool for system calls I was now able to find out that the problem has nothing to do with the SSIS package file. The SQL Server seems to use an application called "DTExec" to execute the packages but this application is simply missing on the new system. I don't know why but this seems to be the problem. Do you know anything about this application? I am not sure if I can just install it on the new SQL Server or why it is even missing to begin with.

Comment: Dtexec is the application used, by SQL server to execute file system deployed packages. If I recall correctly It's part of SQL Server's installation options, so this suggests it wasn't installed.

Answer (score 3):

Having the exact same issue.
Found a workaround, don't like it, but it did get the package run.

Change "Type" from SQL Server Integration Services Package" to "Transact-SQL script (T-SQL)"

Make your SQL Statement something like:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell '""C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /FILE "\"<Path To Package>\<PackageName>.dtsx\""  /WARNASERROR /X86  /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING E'
```

Note that the start of the command `'""` is NOT a type-o, neither is the `\""` right after the `.dtsx` package name.

Don't like this answer, but until the correct solution comes along... it is working.